# Ruby quick sort: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, quicksort

```
def quick_sort(list)
  return list if list.size <= 1
  p = list.sample
  left, right = list.partition{|elmt| elmt <= p}
  quick_sort(left) + quick_sort(right)
end

a = [9,8,7,6,5,0,6]
b = quick_sort(a)
puts b
```

When I run it in the terminal, it shows:

```
quick_sort.rb:4: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

However I could not see any problem on line 4. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `quick_sort` function never reaches a final state. It keeps calling itself until the system stack is exhausted.

Comment: @lightswitch05 Or it recurses too many times and reaches the stack depth limit.

Comment: @DouglasFShearer That's exactly what he just said.

Comment: Ignore me, see my comment on my own (deleted) answer.

Answer (score 4):

You application isn't taking into account duplicate values. In your example, you have `6` twice. Once you break down the array into small enough chunks, you get a chuck like `[6,6]`. When you try to call `partition` on `[6, 6]`, you get `[[6, 6], []]`, which keeps trying to call `quick_sort`. Since it cannot be broken down and further then `[6,6]`, it just keeps running until you fill up your system stack.

A simple solution would be to remove all duplicates before you check the size of the list. If the size is `< 2` after you've removed your duplicates, then you have reached a final state.

Final Solution:

```
def quick_sort(list)
  return list if list.uniq.size < 2
  p = list.sample
  left, right = list.partition{|elmt| elmt <= p}
  quick_sort(left) + quick_sort(right)
end

a = [9,8,7,6,5,0,6]
b = quick_sort(a)
```

Of course, you could always just use Ruby's sorting function too:

```
[9,8,7,6,5,0,6].sort
```